# AMA with UXPin on on Wednesday, October 2nd, 4PM–6PM GMT+02

Tags: discussion

First Ask Me Anything will be on Wednesday, October 2nd from 4pm-6pm GMT+02 [9am EST]

It will be with [UXPin](https://www.uxpin.com/)

> UXPin is a design tool you can use throughout the whole product
>   creation process, including prototyping, collaboration, and handoff.
>
> You can use UXPin to create wireframes, UI designs, and interactive
>   prototypes that feel like the real product. And all that without
>   writing any code whatsoever. Your stakeholders can understand your
>   ideas better and collaborate on iterations in one tool, which makes it
>   easier to develop a real product.
>
> Since UXPin is cloud-based, you can work with it from browsers, but
>   also at desktop apps on Windows, and macOS. This design tool is used
>   by top companies of all sizes like Microsoft and PayPal, but also
>   software houses and freelance designers.

If you're interested, you can find links to the SE chatrooms for the event, and more details here on the [GD.SE meta](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3663/ama-with-uxpin-on-on-wednesday-october-2nd-4pm-6pm-gmt02)

Comment: Would we like to remove the "featured" tag on this now?